# onclientclick event for custom controls

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-controls

I have a div which has custom control in it

```
<div class="modal modal-medium" id="modal-default-email">
            <asp:DefaultMailMessage ID="DefaultMailMessageID" runat="server"   />
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
```

I just want to create a client click event. How? Share your ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the event in you control, implement the [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) for handle postback events and registre the [GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Click")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112(v=vs.110).aspx) clint-side e.g.

more or less is thus

```
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

 public class MyControl : CompositeControl, IPostBackEventHandler
    {
        //Declare event
        public event EventHandler Click;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            //Creante your control 
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            //set your property

            //Set postback reference client-side
            div.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Click"));
         //Add control
         Controls.Add(div);
        }

        protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((this.Click != null)))
            {
                this.Click.Invoke(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(eventArgument, "Click")))
            {
                this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

you see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719907(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: will it be same for onclient click? pls confirm

Comment: This class manage the the click event fired from div on client

Comment: on the div come rendered the attribute  onclick ="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(....)" that manage by ASP.NET with the inteface IPostBackEventHandler